# Cannot post data to API via Curl and PHP

Tags: php

Am working with Blinksky Payments API.

Below is the post parameters

```
URI  https://api.blinksky.com/api/v1
POST /send

{
 "gift": {
      "action": "order",
      "apikey": "{APIKey}",
      "sender": "Athens Automotive Inc.",
      "from": "17705551234",
      "dest": "16150001234",
      "code": "62",
      "amount": 100,
      "postal": "30005",
      "msg": "Thanks for taking our test drive!",
      "reference": "{your_unique_order_id}",
      "handle_delivery": false
    }
}
```

When I tried my code below, it throws error

```
{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

What am I doing wrong? Below is the code:

```
$url = "https://api.blinksky.com/api/v1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$post ='{
 "gift": {
      "action": "order",
      "apikey": "my-api-key-goes-here",
      "sender": "Luxury Automotive Inc.",
      "from": "17705551xxxxxxx",
      "dest": "16150001xxxxxxx",
      "code": "62",
      "amount": 100,
      "postal": "90211",
      "msg": "Thanks for the Gift!",
      "reference": "G62-786",
      "handle_delivery": false
    }
}';


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type:application/json'
));  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: I couldnt find their API docs but I'm pretty confident they wouldn't let you do something like this without authenticating against the API first...you probably need to have an authenicate API call first which will send back a bearer token you can send as header for future requests.

Comment: You are missing the /send path in your url. Change this: $url = "https://api.blinksky.com/api/v1";
 to this $url = "https://api.blinksky.com/api/v1/send";

Comment: Thanks @Anik Chakrabortty. That solve it. You can update it as the right answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the /send path in your url.
Change this:

```
$url = "https://api.blinksky.com/api/v1";
```

to this:

```
$url = "https://api.blinksky.com/api/v1/send";
```